# How to read an INI File with array like sub keys in java

Tags: java, configuration, ini

Does anybody know a JAVA lib where i can read an INI File with that kind of syntax?

```
  [RESPONSE]
  code = 200
  description = Command completed successfully
  queuetime = 0
  runtime = 0.006
  property[count][0] = 164
  property[domain][0] = foo1.at
  property[domain][1] = foo2.at
  property[domain][2] = foo3.at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INI4J: http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

(This was the first entry on Google searching "java ini". Please, search for your own before asking).

For the array-like thing, in the case INI4J doesn't support it, get the left part as a String and parse the array indexes.

Comment: Sorry but this was done before i asked this question. The lib does not handle this in a nice way so i asked here! Whats wrong ...